# Spring DAO testing

Tags: java, spring, testing, dao

I've heard it's recommended to create separated interfaces for the each DAO classes to make it's test easier. The answer on the question "why?" was about of possibility of substitution the original DAO implementation by test one. But there was no info about how to do that.

So, I'm interested how to do that.

Assuming we've the simple DAO interface:

```
public interface PersonDao {
    void add();
    ...
}
```

and the simple as well it's implementation:

```
@Repository
public class PersonDaoImpl implements PersonDao {

   public void add() {
      // doing something
   }
}
```

how can we test it like that:

```
public class PersonDaoTest {

   @Autowire
   FakePersonDao fakePersonDao;

   @Test
   public void addTest() {
      fakePersonDao.add();
   }
}
```

where's the `FakeDao` is second "test" implementation of `PersonDao` interface:

```
public class FakePersonDaoImpl implements PersonDao {

    public void add() {
        // doing something different
    }
}
```

hm?

Should we use everywhere `@Autowired` in combination with `@Qualifier` or there's a better way?

Comment: Use Spring Data, which automatically provides implementations.

Comment: @chrylis, it uses JPA which I don't like to use with Spring MVC together ;( Since it forces to keep the entities and forms as different entities instead of single one

Comment: If you don't want to use the real implementation, then use a mocking framework, like [Mockito](http://mockito.org/). And no, I don't think that you should create an interface for *each* different DAO. You could instead create an interface for reading DAOs, for writing DAOs and so one.

Comment: You can use a JPA entity (or MongoDB document, or other things) as Spring MVC form objects. It's usually not the best idea to couple so tightly, but you can.

Comment: @chrylis, there's the blocker problem which is about nested entities. Since it cannot be passed directly to the controller as field, it forces to send this separately, what makes no sense to use the JPA entity as form :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When people suggest substituting a mock for a real DAO, they're talking about testing the layer that uses the DAO. So if you have a service layer, the test might look like

```
public class MyServiceTest {
    private MyServiceImpl objectUnderTest = new MyServiceImpl();
    private PersonDao fakePersonDao;
    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        fakePersonDao = new FakePersonDao(); // or define it using Mockito
        objectUnderTest.setPersonDao(fakePersonDao);
    }
}
```

This way you can exercise the functionality of the service that needs testing without being dependent on having access to whatever resource the DAO encapsulates.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'm interested is it necessarily to make the setter for the service impl or there's a way to round this using annotations or somehow else?

Comment: @Codemaster reflection would be a way to eliminate the need for a setter.

Comment: @Codemaster: you can use reflection (Spring has a ReflectionTestUtil for that), constructor arguments, or a custom TestConfiguration that autowires dependencies for the test. shouldn't need qualifiers typically.